# JSDoc: how to define a type that's equal to object's property names- like Typescript's keyof?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, jsdoc

I'm looking for a way to get an object's property names as a type using JSDoc.

Let there be a typedef of an object named `Record`

```
/**
 * @typedef {{
      date: string,
      a1: string,
      a2: string,
   }} Record
 */
```

I want the variable `fields` to be documented as equal to the object's properties- which means for this example: `'date' | 'a1' | 'a2'`

```
/**
 * @type {*keyof Record??*} in this case, this will be equal to @type {'date' | 'a1' | 'a2'}
 */
let fields = 'a1';
```

Typescript provides the **keyof** keyword, which does just that. unfortunately, the system I'm working on does not support typescript :\

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
* @typedef {{
* date: string,
* a1: string,
* a2: string,
* }} Record
*/

/** @type {Record['date']|Record['a1']|Record['a2']}*/
let fileds = 'a1';
```

Try this

-New Edit-

If you don't want to list up the types. Maybe you want to try this way.

```
/** @typdef {string} RecordProperty */

/*
* @typedef {{
* date: RecordProperty,
* a1: RecordProperty,
* a2: RecordProperty,
* }} Record
*/

/** @type {RecordProprty} */
let fileds = 'a1';
```

Comment: This gets you to the types of the properties, not their names, right? And in any case it lists out all the properties by name, which the asker seems not to want.

Comment: Right. How about create new typedef for obect's property?

Comment: You're still defining the field as the type of the record's value (RecordProperty = `string`), not the names of the fields (`"a1"`, `"date"`). That isn't what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring a enum-like object, you can just declare the tuple first(or in another `@typedef`):

```
const OPTIONS = /** @type {const} */ (['one', 'two']);
/**
 * @type {typeof OPTIONS[number]}
 * @see OPTIONS
 */
const option = 'two';
// error TS2322: Type '"four"' is not assignable to type '"one" | "two"'.
// /** @type {typeof OPTIONS[number]} */ const invalidOption = 'four';

/**
 * @type {{[Key in OPTIONS[number]]: any}}
 */
const optionObj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  // error TS2322: Type '{ one: number; two: number; four: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ one: any; two: any; }'.
  // four: 4,
};
```

Comment: Your answer uses TypeScript syntax for the type expressions rather than JSDoc syntax. OP wrote "the system I'm working on does not support typescript."